# Use bluetooth controller to execute shell script

Tags: bluetooth, script

How can I use a button on my bluetooth gamepad to execute a shell script on my rpi 3 in raspbian?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used xbindkeys_config which is a seperate package than just the standard xbindkeys. It uses a gui instead of configuring a text file. Also my bluetooth controller had a switch on the back to change from gamepad mode to keyboard mode, which I originally had on gamepad. When switched to keyboard the xbindkeys config easily recognized the buttons and gave me no problems. In the gui I also set the command to run a shell script which was very easy as well. So if your having issues with your keycodes give xbindkeys a try. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction Dallin.